# PHP equivalent for the following CURL code

Tags: php, curl

I have a strange problem with PHP Curl. I want to set post fields option multiple times. What is the equivalent PHP code for the following CURL code:

```
curl -X POST https://example.com \
 -d 'contacts=my_list' \
 -d 'data[]={"email":"address1@domain.com","name":"contactName1"}' \
 -d 'data[]={"email":"address2@domain.com","name":"contactName2"}'
```

I want to send data[] as multiples of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. I already tried setting post field as

```
$post = "?contacts=my_list&data[]=%7B%22email%22%3A%22address1%40domain.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22contactName1%22%7D&data[]=%7B%22email%22%3A%22address2%40domain.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22contactName2%22%7D"
```

Can we have curl set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS two times like

```
$post1 = "contacts=my_list&data[]=%7B%22email%22%3A%22address1%40domain.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22contactName1%22%7D";
$post2 = "data[]=%7B%22email%22%3A%22address2%40domain.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22contactName2%22%7D";
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post1);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post2);
curl_exec($this->ch);
```

Comment: Push these fields to array, then join them with "&". See http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Comment: Also remove "?" from the beginning of $post

Comment: You can also use streams instead of curl - stream_create_context allows you to post when CURL isn't available in PHP.

Comment: @Ukuser32 I will try stream_create_context and let you know...

Comment: @Heavy I already tried it using array and using '&'... I want to know if there is any way in PHP to do -d "....." -d "...." (Two times) like in using CURL through command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is the code you are looking for:

```
<?php
$post1 = "contacts=my_list&data[]=%7B%22email%22%3A%22address1%40domain.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22contactName1%22%7D";
$post2 = "data[]=%7B%22email%22%3A%22address2%40domain.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22contactName2%22%7D";
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post1 . '&' . $post2);
curl_exec($this->ch);
?>
```

**But the best and clearest way** to do it is to put all information in arrays and let `http_build_query()` do the job:

```
<?php
  $c = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://your_url_here.com');
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $postData = array(
   'contacts' => 'my_list',
   'data' => array(
      array('email' => 'address1@domain.com', 'name' => 'contactName1'),
      array('email' => 'address2@domain.com', 'name' => 'contactName2'),
   ),
);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
  curl_exec($c);
?>
```

Comment: I already tried both ways... it is not working... is there a way in php curl I can do -d "..." -d "..." two times like in command prompt...

Comment: @RaviRajendra I updated my answer - try the "cleanest way" again and let me know how it went. If you set different options - also let me know (as it may disturb the process).

Comment: I couldn't make it work with the array as data[0] and data[1] that is generated is not being accepted by the third party API. I ended up generating the entire string and it started working. I think that the problem is that the array is converted into string with "data[0]=...&data[1]=...". The third party API is only allowing "data[]=...&data[]=...". Anyways thanks for the answer... Marking it as the right answer... :)

Comment: That's one bad API then, I'd say... Thanks for accepting though!

Answer (score 1):

I would say not per [curl_setopt documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) :

> This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like
> 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key
> and field data as value.

So better doing a `curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post1."&".$post2)`
Or with  a clean array:

```
$post_data["contacts"] = "my_list";
$post_data["data[0]"] = "%7B%22email%22%3A%22address1%40domain.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22contactName1%22%7D";
$post_data["data[1]"] = "%7B%22email%22%3A%22address2%40domain.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22contactName2%22%7D";
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data);
curl_exec($this);
```

I can't swear how it works with multiple fields like `data[]`, but I think curl does the array under the hood (if not I can't see how it could work on the receiver side).

Edit: saw previous answer after posting this, if its of no use tell me I'll delete it

Comment: Ya, it depends on the API... this third party API I'm using is only accepting data[] and not data[0]... so using it as a array is useless as it would always take the last $post_Data["data[]"]... the solution is to generate the post_data string manually... thanks for the answer...